# Integrar OAuth 2.0 para acceder a las API de Google, con backend Spring Boot v1.5.9

Tags: api, google-api, backend, oauth

Estoy intentando implementar la creación de correos electrónicos para una organización, pero se me pide que el backend sea con Spring Boot y el frontend con AngularJS, a lo cual no tengo mucho conocimiento de como hacer la autorización de OAuth 2.0 para el consumo de las API de Google desde el backend y mostrarle la ventana de consentimiento en el frontend al usuario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví creando una cuenta de servicio:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

y con el codigo:

```
Directory directory = getDirectoryService("correostest@emailtest.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
        if (directory != null) {
            User user = createUser(directory);
        }



private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "correostest@emailtest.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = "/path/emailtest-1234.p12";

public static Directory getDirectoryService(String userEmail) {
    try {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER))
                .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                        new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
                .build();
        GoogleCredential gc = credential.createDelegated("userAdmin@dominio.mx");

        return new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
                .setApplicationName("Nombre proyecto")
                .setHttpRequestInitializer(gc).build();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error(getDirectoryService): " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

public static User createUser(Directory directory) {
    try {
        User user = new User();

        UserName name = new UserName();
        name.setFamilyName("Lopez");
        name.setGivenName("Juan");
        user.setName(name);
        user.setPassword("password101");
        user.setPrimaryEmail("prueba@dominio.mx");

        user = directory.users().insert(user).execute();

        if (user!=null)
            System.out.println("Usuario creado :D");

        return user;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error(createUser): " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

POM.xml

```
<!--Para cuentas de correo google-->
<!--No bajar a mas de la version 22, como minimo de lib guava-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>30.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.30.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.auth/google-auth-library-oauth2-http -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
        <version>0.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-admin-directory -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-admin-directory</artifactId>
        <version>directory_v1-rev118-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-bigquery -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
        <version>v2-rev459-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
```